# Best practice: AmazonS3 service

Tags: php, architecture, amazon-s3

What are best practices for an app that stores user data (files,images,etc.) on AmazonS3 server ?

This app requires that URL to uploaded file be available as soon as it is uploaded (URL is to be stored in database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This app requires that URL to uploaded
>   file be available as soon as it is
>   uploaded (URL is to be stored in
>   database).

The URL should be returned as soon as you upload the file, alternatively you can deduce the URL if you know the File Name, Bucket Name, and base URL (which you should know all 3 of those if you're uploading the file.)

As far as best practices I'd say they're the same whether you're hosting the files yourself or via a CDN. The two most important to me would be:

- security/privacy (set appropriate access permissions on buckets/files)
- data integrity (S3 has two levels of redundancy one is 99.99999% the other 99.9% - consider keeping originals in the higher tier and any derivative files you create, and which you can re-create, can go in the lower tier)